# Database Design for NoSQL Fantasy Baseball League

Tags: database-design, schema, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to create a proper schema to place scraped data into, using a MongoDB database.

Currently it looks like

```
Team {
    id : id,
    name : String,
    teamLink : String,
    username : String,
    userLink : String,
    league : Number,
    Rank : {
        global : Number,
        division : Number
    },
    Points : {
        global : Number,
        division : Number
    }
    Stats : [{
        desc : String,
        value : String,
        globalRank : Number,
        globalPts : Number,
        divRank : Number,
        divPts : Number
    }]
}

League {
    id : Number,
    name : String,
    link : String,
    division : Number,
    acrive : Boolean
    rankings : [{
        week : Number,
        ranks : [{
            team : String,
            position : Number,
            points : Number
        }]
    }]
}
```

The problem is that a lot of this makes it hard to quickly rank over something as simple as a single stat (e.g. HR). So I am trying to better understand on how to model the data to say, quickly sort over HRs or easily obtain the rankings. I come from a relational db background so I am having a hard time adjusting without joins.

Thank you

Comment: I hate to burst your bubble but this is structured relational data, and would likely work a LOT better in a SQL database.

Comment: Fully aware it would work a hell of a lot better under a relational database; however, this was more of a learning exercise than anything else. 

What would be the optimal way to arrange it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Team {
    id : id,
    name : String,
    teamLink : String,
    username : String,
    userLink : String,
    league : Number,
    Stats : [{
        desc : String,
        value : String,
        globalRank : Number,
        globalPts : Number,
        divRank : Number,
        divPts : Number,
        year:Number
    }]
}

League {
    id : Number,
    name : String,
    link : String,
    division : Number,
    acrive : Boolean
}

rankings : {
            week : Number,
            league_id: Number,
            year: Number,
            ranks : [{
                team_id : Number,
                position : Number,
                points : Number
            }]
        }

match {
       id : Number,
       league : Number
       team_visit : Number,
       team_ext : Number,
       ining : Number,
       time_start : Datetime,
       time_game : Number,
       team_visit_score : Number,
       team_ext_score : Number    
}
```

**EDIT: explain schema.**

- First is necessary separate all stats for team in a interval time,
  because changes in time for season, years, stats, etc...
- Add the match documents, for each match a document. Separate all
  for    documents, League, Teams, Ranks, is better for search and
  relation    with others team in match, rank...
- And the solution is `MySQL` I'm not so sure about that, because if you 
  have a lots data in match, league, teams, ranks... Is Better documents with all stats of any team, or all rank in any interval time
  because in `MySQL` you need `JOINS` for that.